# Get single values and sum of all the output in mysql

Tags: mysql, sum

`SELECT value FROM table` produces this result:

```
1
5
8
3
```

But I want to get the single values and the sum of all the output

```
1    17
5    17
8    17
3    17
```

`SELECT value,SUM(value) FROM table` produces just only

```
1    17
```

How can I somehow "ungroup" my results?

Thanks for your answers.....

Comment: post your table structure with sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a sub-query:

```
SELECT value, (SELECT SUM(value) FROM table) AS sValue
FROM table
```

You can alternatively use a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT value, sValue
FROM mytable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(value) AS sValue FROM mytable) AS t
```

Comment: Is this the only way? Because I have many WHERE terms and I would have to use the same terms a second time for the sub-query.

Comment: @SvenRichter As far as I know MySQL doesn't support CTEs, hence IMO there is no ohter way but to repeat all the predicates in the `WHERE` clause. Using a `CROSS JOIN` is more or less equivalent to the previous method.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the `SUM` on every row you could use user variables:

```
 SELECT value, @sum := @sum + value AS cumulative
   FROM table1
   JOIN (SELECT @sum := 0) init
  WHERE ...
```

This will give you a cumulative sum and the last row will have the correct total.

Alternatively, assuming this is part of an application and you are looping through the results to display them, it may be easier to perform the calculation in the application logic.